# Select column values not present in group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table consisting of customer purchase records having following columns

```
CUSTOMER  TRANSDATE  SALENUM  STORE  TRANSTYP  PRICE  
--------  --------- --------- ----- --------- ------
  1     12-FEB-2013    777      O     CASH      7.99
  1     12-FEB-2013    777      O     CASH      6.99
  1     12-FEB-2013    778      O     CARD      9.17
  2     23-APR-2013    987      D     CASH      7.65
  1     15-MAY-2013    1098     T     CARD      2.35
```

I want to aggregate over salenum i,e for each salenum, i want the total price, as well as the store, transtyp, transdate,customer values as these are same for a particular salenum

However if i use

```
select customer,transdate,salenum,store,transtyp,sum(price) from table1 group by salenum
```

Its obviously saying not a valid group by value. How to get the desired result?

SAMPLE RESULT:

```
CUSTOMER  TRANSDATE  SALENUM  STORE  TRANSTYP  PRICE  
--------  --------- --------- ----- --------- ------
  1     12-FEB-2013    777      O     CASH      15.98
  1     12-FEB-2013    778      O     CARD       9.17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All non-aggregated columns should be in the group by:

```
select customer,transdate,salenum,store,transtyp,sum(price)
from table1 
group by customer,transdate,salenum,store,transtyp
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. So as there distinct values only in salenum compared to others, it groups correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is actually grouping by everything, but if all other columns are always the same for a given `salenum`, you get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CUSTOMER,TRANSDATE,SALENUM,STORE,TRANSTYP,SUM(PRICE)
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY CUSTOMER,TRANSDATE,SALENUM,STORE,TRANSTYP
ORDER BY CUSTOMER
```

I using the order by clause because it will be in order and also in sequence.

Comment: What if OP wants to order by date? :P

Comment: Just use the column which they need accordingly. In general im using as customer for this case.